# select disabled al seleccionar un valor - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Al seleccionar un valor de mi select necesito que quede deshabilitado todo el select como tal y solo muestre el valor que seleccione, he intentado de varias formas pero no he logrado hacer que me funcione. Además necesito  que aparezca un boton que diga activar y al darle clic el select vuelva a quedar activo.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function Pruebas() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState();

  const elselect =  () => {
   
    
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        
        <select  onChange={ elselect }>
          <option value="uno">uno</option>
          <option value="uno">dos</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podrias crear otro estado que te indique si el select esta desabilitado o no y este valor se actualizaria cuando se seleccione un valor en el select

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Pruebas() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState();
  const [selectDisabled, setSelectDisabled] = useState(false);

  const elselect = (e) => {
    setSelect(e.target.value);
    setSelectDisabled(true);
  };

  const enableSelect = () => {
    setSelectDisabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <select onChange={elselect} disabled={selectDisabled}>
          <option value="uno">uno</option>
          <option value="dos">dos</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <button onClick={enableSelect}>activar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

luego al hacer click en el boton se volveria a habilitar ese estado